# 2 Flash overlapping no interaction on Firefox Macintosh

Tags: macos, flash, firefox

I've got a web page with two different floating divs (position: absolute) and both contains a flash movie. The two are overlapping and the one below is a lot bigger.
The problem is: on the LAST VERSION of FIREFOX for MACINTOSH (snow leopard) the flash movie on top is impossible to interact with!

Watch yourself (wait for the fullscreen video to close): http://clients.adrime.com/files/campaigns/3509758016/27221/IT_pourfemme.it_index.html

How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old questions but I thought I'd throw a possible solution that I've come across.

I had a very similar issue as described above. Two SWF movies loaded into a page sitting on top of one another. The top most contents mouse position was always off by a decent margin making the buttons almost unusable.

One of my movies was 1000x650 the other 1200x650. The larger of the two had a left positioning equivalent to around -100px which appeared to be the same offset being seen in the top most movie.

By giving both movies the same left positioning, the issue was resolved. Most annoyingly this only occurred on Firefox on Mac / OSX.

Some other discussions around this subject can be found in the comments here:
http://snook.ca/archives/other/hit_bug_in_fire

It appears to be a consistent bug, I'm surprised it hasn't been addressed.